# How to clean up material-ui withStyles when done with React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, material-ui, jss

I'm looking at heap snapshots, and I'm seeing stuff like:

[image]

So I'm curious: How do we make sure Material UI stuff is cleaned up when we're done with it (done using a styled component), just in case?

I'm not sure if I have any leaks in this area (i.e. maybe not Material UI's fault), but in the heap snapshot there's clearly some array that is not referenced by JS and stuck around in Material UI code, which may be because I forgot to clean something else up.

Also you can see the [JSS](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss) lib under Material UI.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with your investigation? Just starting using Material UI for a big project and seeing a lot of memory getting used, but haven't yet seen a viable solution.

Comment: I never solved that, but I have since then made my own entirely different non-React-based solution over at http://github.com/lume/element. It is a simple custom-element =-based component system that relies on standards for things like style scoping. It's been working great for me, and it is quite simple and thus everything's under my control (no need for CSS-in-JS, we can just pass any JS expression into the CSS template strings, and write very simple selectors thanks to Shadow DOM). I really dislike the convoluted nature of the React ecosystem.